# Regarding the output of "df -h" in Linux

Tags: filesystems, mount, df

Regarding the output of "df -h" in Linux.

```
[root@]# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2             193G   82G  101G  45% /
tmpfs                 1.9G  272K  1.9G   1% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1             486M   28M  433M   7% /boot
/dev/sda3              49G  759M   45G   2% /home
[root@]#
```

Here I am unable to understand what is `/dev/sda1` `/dev/sda2` `/dev/sda3` `tmpfs` and correspoding Column (`mounted on`) `/boot` `/` `/home` `/dev/shm` .\

Can anyone please explain these terms?

Answer (score 6):

Every device in linux has device node under `/dev/` (The default).

Pattern is: **Hard Disk type,Hard Disk Number,Partition Number**

- `sd` means **SATA** hard disk
- `hd` means **IDE** hard disk
- `a` means **First** hard disk , `b` **Second** and so on.
- `1` **First** partition, `2` **Second** and so on.

For example:

`sda1` means First SATA hard disk and partition.

`sdb1` means Second SATA hard disk and First partition

`hda2` means First IDE hard disk and Second partition

/boot or / or /home are directories... When linux boots up it mount partitions under `/dev/` to specified directories. From your `df -h` output `/dev/sda1` mounted on `/boot` directory.. But why mount?! Because if you want to use hard disk you need to mount partition to a directory for access and use it.

**tmpfs**: Tmpfs is a file system which keeps all files in virtual memory.
For more details read following links:
http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/what-is-devshm-and-its-practical-usage.html
https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/tmpfs.txt

Comment: Actually, since kernel version 2.6.20 both [SATA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA) and [PATA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_ATA) devices, including devices on a IDE bus receive a **sd** prefix.

Comment: Thanks .. But what is tempfs and what is the speciality of tempfs ? and what the correstponding /dev/shm ?

Comment: Can we rename the names as userdefined ... /dev/sda3 as /dev/asdf_home

Comment: Ur welcome, Please read my edited post, For your second question you can do everything in linux but you may need to change kernel..

Comment: *"Every device in linux has directory under /dev/."* Not true either as stated or to the exclusion of other possibilities. First off, those are *device nodes*, not directories (though device nodes are exposed as directory *entries*, which is something else). Second, device nodes *can* exist anywhere, and while /dev is the customary place it's really just a directory like any other.

Answer (score 3):

`/dev/sda1`, `/dev/sda2` and `/dev/sda3` are the [first, second and third partition](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/87305/43779) respectively of the first [PATA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_ATA) or [SATA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA) device, which are [mounted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3192/43779) at certain points in the [file system hierarchy](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/).

The `/` indicates the root of the file system hierachy. The `/boot` directory contains files needed during the boot process and `/home` typically contains the files owned by regular users.

[`tmpfs`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs) is a special file system which stores files in physical memory instead of on disk. As they are stored in [volatile memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volatile_memory), they will disappear when the system is rebooted unless copied to disk  storage. The particular `tmpfs` instance you see is mounted at [`dev/shm`](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/what-is-devshm-and-its-practical-usage.html) which is a shared memory implementation for passing data between processes.