# Can't figure out what all these sd drives are

Tags: linux, ntfs

So I created a WindowsXP install using an NTFS drive in VMPlayer and now I want to make an image of it using dd. Here is the diskpart info from Windows:
[image]

Then I use Kali as a live-cd and I find like a millions sd drives under /dev:

[image]

I was able to create the image from /dev/sddq1, but I want to know what all those extra drives are.

Anyone?

**Edited to show the results of lsblk**
[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Looks like vmplayer is doing something silly.  What does `lsblk` show?

Comment: See above and tell me what you think.

Comment: Instead of pictures, copying and pasting the text would be better, but yes, it seems that vmplayer is emulating a whole ton of virtual disk drives that are each only one sector long, which seems to be a rather silly thing to do.

Comment: You can't copy and paste it out of the VM without installing the tools package, which I haven't :(

Comment: Or you could open stackexchange inside the vm instead of outside ;)

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/87305/116858