# Partitions and Drives

Tags: files, partition, directory

As far I know, my drive is mounted under `/dev` directory as `/dev/sda` and the partitions are mounted as `/dev/sda1` or `/dev/sda2` but I have to go to `/media/DATA` to access my data on a partition. [This page](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/87300/152971) says that `/dev/sda` is called a drive and `/dev/sdb1` is called a partition. I want to ask what `/media/DATA` is called and how do I find(using command-line of course) `/media/DATA` if I know of `/dev/sdb1` or vice-versa.

Comment: `/media/DATA` is a mounted file system that exists on a partition `/dev/sda1`  that exists on a drive `/dev/sda`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/media/DATA` is your mounted **file system**.

`/dev/sda1` is the **partition**.

`/dev/sda` is the **drive**.

If you wanted to interact with the file system, say create a file, you would interact with `/media/DATA`.

If you wanted to interact with the partition, say format or create a file system you would interact with `/dev/sda1`.

If you wanted to interact with the drive itself, say backup your partition table `dd if=/dev/sda of=/media/DATA/partition_table.img bs=512 count=1` you would interact with `/dev/sda`.

Comment: :How do I find which partition is linked to which mounted file system or vice-versa?

Comment: Use the `mount` command. It will list the mount point to the partition. Depending on your version you may need the list switch. `mount -l`.

Comment: Just one last question: Is it possible to backup a partition same way as you took a backup for the drive?

Comment: Not sure what exactly you are asking. If you want to create a backup of a partition, say your OS, you could use tools like `clonezilla` or even `dd`.

Comment: What I want to ask is whether it is possible to use `dd` to create backup of a partition as in `dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/media/somewhere/abc.img`?

Comment: Yes, your syntax is also correct. Be aware that it is a bit for bit backup, meaning that if the partition is 10GB the image file will be 10GB. There are ways to make it smaller, though. Like zero out all free space then pipe dd through a compressor.