# Confusion about naming: increase a directory / partition / filesystem / block device?

Tags: fedora, filesystems, partition, disk-usage

I'm a new linux user (Fedora, LXDE). Now I have some troubles with increasing the size of... partition? Directory? Filesystem? ...`/usr`. This is my question.

What exactly I want to do is to "increase the size of `/usr`" in order to install new packages. Increasing is a separate problem - maybe I would need to increase size of something different (maybe even delete partition with Windows) - here I'm asking about naming.

If I'm increasing the size of `/usr`, am I increasing the size of **partition** `/usr`, **directory** `/usr`, **filesystem** `/usr`, **block device** `/usr` (because `gnome-disk-utility` says `/dev/fedora/usr` is a block device), or something different? Or "increasing" is a misconception here, or I'm increasing something different?

*Sorry for the title, I didn't know how to name my problem (thus my question could be too subjective and deleted, I understand that).*

EDIT 1: I'm asking in the context of my output of `df` command:

```
/dev/mapper/fedora-usr                           2,9G  2,7G   42M  99% /usr
```

EDIT 2: Well, now I have thought it through and consider that the size of `/dev/mapper/fedora-usr` is the size to increase.

Comment: What's the output of `vgdisplay` and `lsblk`?

Comment: But what would it be for?

Answer (score 5):

This *is* confusing. First, `/usr` is a *directory*. But any directory can also be a *mount point*, which is where a *filesystem* is anchored. The filesystem by itself is on a *block device* — this can be either a partition, a logical volume, or a file attached to a loopback device.

There are certain directories which by tradition are often separate mount points, and `usr` is one of them. I think the easiest way to find out the state of a given system is with the `df` command — give it the name of a directory, and it will tell you information about the filesystem that directory is under. For example, on my system:

```
$ df -h /usr
Filesystem           Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/fedora-root   79G   19G   57G  25% /
```

Which shows that for *me*, `/usr` is on the "root" filesystem, which is on the device `/dev/mapper/fedora-root`, which is mounted mounted at `/`. On your system, based on your update, `/usr` is separate.

For comparison:

```
$ df -h /home/mattdm/
Filesystem           Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/fedora-home   99G   74G   21G  79% /home
```

which tells me that my home directory is on a filesystem mounted at `/home`.

Whether or not a *particular* directory is a mount point, to make more space available under *any* directory, you need to increase the space on the filesystem on which that directory resides. In my case, since `/usr` is on the 
`/dev/mapper/fedora-root` filesystem mounted at `/`, I would need to increase the size of that `/dev/mapper/fedora-root`. In *your* case, `/usr` is the mount point for the `/dev/mapper/fedora-usr` filesystem, so you need to increase the size of *that* filesystem.

To make more space on `/usr` in your situation, you will first need to have a *logical volume* with enough space — you can add *physical volumes* to that if there is no room free. Then, you will need to grow the `filesystem` inside that logical volume too. (This can be done in one step with the `--resizefs` flag to `lvextend`.)

Comment: OK, `/usr` is **a directory**, so it follows that I have to increase the size of "a directory `/usr`"? I believe a directory cannot have its size, but I'm new to linux and its naming. On the other hand, you wrote: "too", so I understand that growing the filesystem isn't always the same as increasing the size that appears in the `df` output (but could be the same). I know that there are at least 3 "filesystem" meanings in the context of linux.

Merging with @dr01's answer: you mean `/usr` is located on a partition, so I got to increase this partition, and the size in `df` output will grow?

Comment: Yes, `/usr` is mounted in its own partition, different from the root partition `/`.  So you need 1) to increase that partition and 2) to increase the size of the filesystem accordingly.  Once you've done that, the `/usr` directory will be able to hold more stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I'm taking on from @mattdm's good answer to show you the practical steps to do what you need.

The output of `df`

```
/dev/mapper/fedora-usr                           2,9G  2,7G   42M  99% /usr
```

shows that you are using [LVM (Logical Volume Manager)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Volume_Manager_(Linux)), and that the `/usr` directory is mounted on a LV (Logical Volume) named `usr` on the VG (Volume Group) named `fedora`.

Therefore you need to do this:

1) Add a new (physical or virtual) disk to the machine to provide the extra disk space; let's call it `/dev/sdc`.

2) Create a new partition `/dev/sdc1` (of type 0x8E = Linux
LVM) on the new disk:

```
fdisk /dev/sdc
```

(I'm assuming you know how to proceed on this so I'm leaving out the details: press **n**, **p**, **1**, etc.)

This is not necessary but recommended, because if you have other
OSes accessing the disk they might not recognize LVM and see the whole
unpartitioned disk as empty.

3) Initialize the new partition as a Physical Volume:

```
pvcreate /dev/sdc1
```

4) Add the newly created PV to the existing Volume Group:

```
vgextend fedora /dev/sdc1
```

5) Extend the Logical Volume `usr` - and the underlying filesystem as well - so that it takes all free space:

```
lvresize -l+100%FREE --resizefs /dev/mapper/fedora-usr
```

Your `/usr` partition is now larger of whatever the size of `/dev/sdc` was.

Comment: OK, so you do mean that `/usr` is **a partition**, and I have to increase the size of "a partition `/usr`"? Also, from @mattdm's answer, I guess it's not true that `/usr` is a partition in every case (in the context of resizing).

Comment: Yes to everything you said.  The minimal partitioning scheme is to put everything in `/`, but usually one creates a separate partition for `/home`.  And is not uncommon to create also a separate partition for `/var` (so that if the logs in `/var/log/` explode, they don't take down the root filesystem with them) or, as in your case, `/usr`.  It all depends for what your machine is used.

Comment: OK, to sum up, also according to your comment in @mattdm's answer and his answer: `/usr` is a mount point - for a directory named `/usr` (with slash because I mean the filesystem path) - and that directory is under the filesystem  `/dev/mapper/fedora-usr` - and that filesystem is _anchored_ on that mount point (which just means it's accessible from there, right?) - and it's _located_ at the partition =?= block device `/dev/fedora/usr` (as in `gnome-disks`). My problem is with "partition" and "physical volume" - how are they related to each other and to the `/dev/mapper/fedora-usr` filesystem?

Comment: Not exactly.  `/dev/mapper/fedora-usr` is a LVM device accessible (as all Linux devices) via a subdir of `/dev`.  This LVM device is *mounted* (not *anchored*) at `/usr`.  A *volume* must be split into one or more *partitions*, which have to be formatted - i.e. a *filesystem* must be written on them - prior to be usable.  See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87300/differences-between-volume-partition-and-drive  What helps in confusing you here is that your disks use LVM, which is an abstraction (and a very useful tool) over standard partitions; see https://www.howtoforge.com/linux_lvm

Comment: OK, I see you try to teach me, but I'm a very... [searching in dict]... [recalcitrant](https://www.diki.pl/slownik-angielskiego?q=oporny), non-native english-speaking student. ; - ) I will think it over what you wrote. But for now, to be more confused, I see that: (1) `usermount` says `/dev/mapper/fedora-usr` is a "device", (2) `fdisk` says it's a "disk", (3) `df` says it's a "filesystem", (4) GParted doesn't displaying such a string, and (5) `gnome-disks` says (in "mount options") that you can "identify" it (what? mount point?) "as" `/dev/mapper/fedora-usr`.